# Get Lowest Time From Each Group Issue

Tags: mysql, time, group-by, min

I'm trying to get the lowest time for each group but I can't get it to work properly, the `min()` function seems to be not working and just returns the first record it finds for each group.

Query I tried:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(IF(LENGTH(`time`)<6,CONCAT('00:',`time`),`time`))) 
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY `number`;
```

Time field / column NEEDS to be in Varchar format!.

Expected Result:

```
1 - 59:09 - name3
2 - 48:02 - name2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972be/1

Comment: The `Time` column doesn't need to be a varchar. If anything, it needs to be in a format conducive to storing time. That's how databases work. You just need to display it as a varchar by converting when using it in the select list or (even better) in the client code.

Comment: needs to be varchar as it stores different data types in the same column depending on the type of record (speedruns, kills, rounds etc), not all records are time based, just need to work out how to get the lowest time for each 'number' group

Comment: That's kind of a weak schema design, putting different types of data in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dude, you got the right way just need a little bit adjustment.

```
select t1.`number`, t1.`name`,t1.`time` from
  (SELECT `number`,`name`,`time`,
          TIME_TO_SEC(IF(LENGTH(`time`)<6,CONCAT('00:',`time`),`time`)) as `min`
  FROM `test` GROUP BY `number`,`name`)t1
  left join
 (SELECT `number`,`name`,`time`,
         TIME_TO_SEC(IF(LENGTH(`time`)<6,CONCAT('00:',`time`),`time`)) as `min`
 FROM `test` GROUP BY `number`,`name`)t2
    on t1.`number`=t2.`number` and t1.`min` > t2.`min`
 where t2.`number` is null;
```

New one

```
 select t1.`map`,t1.`record`,t1.`name` from
(select `map`,`record`,`name`,
 replace(IF(LENGTH(`achieved`)<6,CONCAT('00:',`achieved`),`achieved`),':','') as mins
 from `records` where `record` = 'speedrun') t1
inner join
(select `map`,
min(replace(IF(LENGTH(`achieved`)<6,CONCAT('00:',`achieved`),`achieved`),':','')) as mins
from `records`
where `record` = 'speedrun' group by `map`) t2
on t1.`map` = t2.`map` and t1.mins = t2.mins
```

Comment: that seems to be returning all records in order of time, i need the lowest time from each group (number)

Comment: @ChrisH sorry i m testing it and find out the group by only effect for the concat part not for min() part, that's y it failed for you and me, i ll edit this later to fix it

Comment: @ChrisH Now it's done, you can just try it. here is my fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972be/21

Comment: okay, works but a little confusing to me (im a sql noobie) now im having trouble adjusting it the my real work scenario, dont suppose you could help me on it, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e2dbf i need to do the same thing but WHERE `record` = 'speedrun' , get the lowest time for each map, also need to access all fields within the row / record (not included in the fiddle) so maybe select * ? but thank you so much for the help btw, been stumped on this for a long time

Comment: @ChrisH it's the same as i show you and i really really don't suggest you to use time_to_sec in this case. hey , you know what? i just got a great idea! you can just use replace to remove the : in time just replace(IF(LENGTH(`time`)<6,CONCAT('00:',`time`),`time`),':',''). and you can use min on it in the right way, it will be much easy and i think you can understand it

Comment: will you be able to write the sql query for it usingn the latest fiddle db please, i dont understand what you mean sorry

Comment: @ChrisH http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0702b/20 done. and i edit my answer to add this part of code, dude you really should accept my answer :)

Comment: To make this a good answer, you should explain what was wrong with the original code, and what you added to make it work. Links to documentation or other sources are always a good idea as well.